# .net XmlSerializer record vs. element

Tags: .net, serialization, xml-serialization, deserialization, xmlserializer

I’m trying to influence the XmlSerializer to create this simple output:

```
<ListOfStuff>
    <PropertyList>
         <Datum qualifier="areaType">square</Datum>
         <Datum qualifier="color">red</Datum>
    </PropertyList>
</ListOfStuff>
```

My objects are decorated like so:

```
public class ListOfStuff
{     
    [XmlElement]
    public PropertyList PropertyList { get; set; }        
}

public class PropertyList
{
    [XmlElement]
    public List<Datum> Datum { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string qualifier { get; set; }
}
```

But the serializer output seems to be interpreting my Datum element as a record rather than an element that has data (the values “square” and “red” are missing).

```
<ListOfStuff>
    <PropertyList>
                 <Datum qualifier="areaType" />
                 <Datum qualifier="color" />
   </PropertyList>
</ListOfStuff>
```

Is there an additional attribute I need to apply to provide more clarity to the serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`[XmlText]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute.aspx) attribute to bind the value of the `<Datum>` elements to a string-valued property in the `Datum` class:

```
public class Datum
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string qualifier { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UCPzvJ).